# How to reload the webpage with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this function below to force reload the webpage when you run the file.

The thing is that the function it's supposed to work just once, but everytime I run it works twice.

Some help please with this function:

```
    function forcedReload(){
        if(!window.location.hash) {
            window.location = window.location + '#';
            window.location.reload(true);

        }
    }
```

As you can see, the function adds a # at the end of the URL when it's done, but instead of adding one adds two.

Comment: may be your forcedReload function getting called twice.

Comment: `window.location = window.location + '#';` - reloads
`window.location.reload(true);` also reloads

Comment: I checked it a lot of times and it isn't that

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? If you just want to add a hash, change `window.location.hash="#"` - but what is the usecase???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mplungjan suggested adding `window.location.hash = "#"` does the required:

```js
function forcedReload() {
  console.log(window.location.href, window.location.hash);
  if (!window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location + "#";
    window.location.hash = "#";
    window.location.reload(true);
  }
}
console.log(window.location.href, window.location.hash);
```

```html
<button onclick="forcedReload()">refresh</button>
```